# Build error: cannot find libxml2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to build 32bit application on 64bit Debian 7 and something goes wrong:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2

```
locate~
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.8.0
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-I. -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/lua50 -I/usr/local/include    
LIBLINK=-L/usr/lib64 -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -lm -llualib50 -llua50 -ldl -lboost_thread -lmysqlclient -Wl,-Map=otserv.map    
ENDFLAGS=-m32 -Winvalid-pch -O2 -include "preheaders.h"
```

Comment: According to the `locate` result `-L/usr/lib64` is obviously wrong.

Comment: now: 

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a when searching for -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread

Comment: Also I'm not sure that linking a 32bit application to 64bit libraries will work out well.